# interactive brokers reqRealTimeBars only working in debugger

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

I do a request

```
def ib_thread():
    global top_of_book_data

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    ib = init_ib()

    contract = Stock(selected_ticker, 'SMART', 'USD')
    ib.errorEvent += error_handler
    ib.qualifyContracts(contract)
    ib.reqMarketDataType(2)
    # Request historical data for the last minute
    sub_successful = ib.reqRealTimeBars(contract, 5, 'TRADES', 0)
    last_heatbeat = ib.reqCurrentTime()
    bars = ib.realtimeBars()
    print(bars)
```

and bars shows [[]]. If I do multiple ib.reqRealTimeBars, bars becomes [[], []], and so on.

Now, if I stop execution in the middle here and do ib.reqCurrentTime() in the debugger for a heartbeat, bars suddenly populates with valid data! No thread change, and the debugger doesn't change lines

But if I run reqCurrentTime just as part of the program it continues to return blanks. tried `time.sleep(5)` after the subscription to make sure it wasn't a delay. Then just ran requesting the realtimebars in a loop. Nothing works.  Whats going on?